# Confused writing this program

Tags: c++

New to coding. The first part in the first link which is the character letter 'a' is correct. But then after that, its downhill from there.

[image]

Its showing me whats wrong, but I do not understand it.
[image]

Comment: Please _never_ post code or screen output as screenshots

Answer (score 2):

You have declared several variables with the same name 'number' in the same scope.  That is not allowed and leads to the error messages.

Answer (score 2):

Within a scope (such as a function or loop or something), you can only declare a variable once.  Otherwise, it would be ambiguous which one you were talking about.

The error is saying you've already declared a variable called `number` (as an int), and you cannot declare it again within the same scope.

Make the second variable called something else:

```
double dNumber = 1.11;
cout << "Please enter a double: " << dNumber << endl;

bool bNumber = 0;
cout << "Please enter a bool: " << bNumber << endl;
```

Note, it's usually more typical to set `bool` values to either `true` or `false`.

Now, if you *really, really* wanted to use the variable name `number` multiple times, you could put each section in curly braces:

```
{
   double number = 1.11;
   cout << "Please enter a double: " << number << endl;
}

{
   bool number = 0;
   cout << "Please enter a bool: " << number << endl;
}
```

In that case, you would no longer have access to that variable outside the curly braces, thus the reference is no longer ambiguous.